Uploading image to AWS using s3 bucket
import { PutObjectCommand, S3Client } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
import uniqid from "uniqid"

    export async function POST(req){
    const data = await req.formData();
    if(data.get('file')){
        // console.log('File Uploaded', data.get('file'))
        // uploading the file to aws s3
        const file = data.get('file')

        const s3Client = new S3Client({
            region : 'eu-north-1',
            credentials : {
                accessKeyId : process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                secretAccessKey : process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY,
            },
        });

        const ext = file.name.split('.').slice(-1)[0] //take the images with.jpeg.jpg etc extension
        const newFileName = uniqid()  + '.' + ext  //to get some random string
        // console.log({newFileName});

        const chunks = [];
        for await (const chunk of file.stream()){
            chunks.push(chunk)
        }

        const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks)

        const bucket = "food-ordering-system"
        await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand({
            Bucket : bucket,
            Key : newFileName,
            ACL : 'public-read', //for file to be publicly available
            ContentType : file.type,
            Body : buffer,
        }));
        
        const link = 'https://'+bucket+'.s3.amazonaws.com/'+ newFileName
        return Response.json(link);
    }
    return Response.json(true)
}

It is resulting in 500 internal server error and in the terminal the following message is shown:

⨯ TypeError: aws_sdk_client_s3__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_.S3Client.send is not a function
at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/upload/route.jsx:35:72)

I tried almost everything but no result improvement as such.

check here, might help https://medium.com/@tiagobertolo/upload-a-picture-to-aws-s3-using-node-js-6eee3641deb6
